# tweak Module to paste values only, not formulas

Tags: excel, vb.net, copy-paste

Can someone please assist me.  I run the module below and it works fine but it pastes the contents of the cells(formulas) rather than the values.  I know it is a paste special for the values but not sure where to tweak.  Also I would like on the to copy the rows out of a variable table which spans A:K and then paste into an identicle table.  sorry if not clear, not sure why the code is displaying funny below.  Starts from sub:

```
Sub armine_profitTEST()
    Dim r As Long, endRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long

    endRow = 500 ' of course it's best to retrieve the last used row number via a function
    pasteRowIndex = 5

    For r = 1 To endRow 'Loop through sheet1 and search for your criteria

        If Cells(r, Columns("F").Column).Value = "Armine" Then 'Found
            'Copy the current row
            Rows(r).Select
            Selection.Copy

            'Switch to the sheet where you want to paste it & paste
            Sheets("Armine").Select
            Rows(pasteRowIndex).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

           'Next time you find a match, it will be pasted in a new row
            pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1

           'Switch back to your table & continue to search for your criteria
            Sheets("Summary").Select
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `pasteSpecial`:

```
Dim xRng As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range

xRng.PasteSpecial(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteFormulas)
```

Comment: sorry to be ignorant but where in the above code do i place it?

Comment: @user2119567 This is an example. You have to paste the data you want, in your case I think it should be `Selection`. And you have to paste where and where you want, of course O.o